# Date parsing with date-io error Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `g`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Hello I got problem with parsing my date

```
                  .map((column) => {
                return column.column.dataType === "DATE" ? (
                  <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                    {format(
                      new Date(parseFloat(column.value)),
                      dateFormat,
                      new Date()
                    )}
                    {console.log(parseFloat(column.value))}
                  </TableCell>
```

heres the code where I format my date.

```
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";

return (
<Provider store={store}>
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <ApplicationContainer />
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
</Provider>);
```

This is my App.js

still I get this error Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `g`

Comment: Could you please include the string you're trying to format?

Comment: sure sir, 1633263540000 here it is

Comment: It's date converted into milliseconds

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `dateFormat`

Comment: It's format function that throwing error. If u wanted the place where console says error is here it is app/node_modules/date-fns/esm/format/index.js:423

Comment: const dateFormat = () => {
    return config && config.dateFormat
      ? config.dateFormat + " HH:mm"
      : getDefaultTimeFormat();
  };

Comment: this is getDefaultTimeFormat()
export const getDefaultTimeFormat = () => {
  return "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm";
};

Comment: Could you please share the code for the `format` function as well? Is there a possibility that `config.dateFormat` contains the letter `g`?

Comment: `import format from "date-fns/format";` format is from here

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy` this is config.dateFormat

Comment: I would double check your code to see where the letter `g` is coming from. I've replicated your code, using your exact values and it's running perfectly on my end.

Comment: Yes its definitely string somewhere coz now I got `r` in error instead of `g` I'll check again ty so much